# Changing to a random background causing lag on android

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to change the background of my game and it's working, but also causing lag on android.

I've tied two different solutions but with the same results. First off the background change is managed by an int variable that has a random value between two numbers and a float that increases every second by 10f, that is used as score.

There's some other code in here as well but i've removed them separately and it seems like it's the background code that is causing the lag.

Here is the current code:

```
        rand1 = Random.Range(0, 4);
        rand2 = Random.Range(4, 8);
        rand3 = Random.Range(8, 12);


        //start off with a random blue background
        BGlist[rand1].SetActive(true);
        // BGmesh.material = BGmat[rand];  //OTHER SOLUTION - change material of mesh renderer

    }


    void Update()
    {
        //Set starttext to false if the character move
        if (lvlmang.left || lvlmang.right)
        {
            startText.SetActive(false);

            //every second score and speed increases
            aliveTime += Time.deltaTime;
            if (aliveTime >= 1)
            {
                scores += 10f;
                scores2 += 10f;
                speedManager += 10f;

                speedManager2 += 10f;

                speedManager3 += 10f;




                scoreText.text = scores.ToString();
                scoreText2.text = scores2.ToString();
                aliveTime -= (int)aliveTime; //reset
            }

        }
        //Increase speed after 8 seconds
        if (speedManager == 80f)
        {
            pControl.speed += 0.25f;
            speedManager = 0f;
        }

        //start screen fade every 30 seconds (preparing for background change)
        if (speedManager2 == 300f)
        {
           fadingBG.StartFading();
            speedManager2 = 0f;
        }

        if (speedManager3 == 310f || speedManager3 == 1213)
        {
            //Random yellow background


            //Set the previous backgrounds game object to false
                BGlist[0].SetActive(false);
                BGlist[1].SetActive(false);
                BGlist[2].SetActive(false);
                BGlist[3].SetActive(false);



            BGlist[rand2].SetActive(true);  //Random yellow background
            //BGmesh.material = BGmat[rand]; // OTHER SOLUTION - change material of mesh renderer
            fadingBG.StopFading();
            speedManager3 += 1f;

        }


        if (speedManager3 == 611f || speedManager3 == 1514)
        {
            //Random red background


            //Set the previous backgrounds game object to false
            BGlist[4].SetActive(false);
            BGlist[5].SetActive(false);
            BGlist[6].SetActive(false);
            BGlist[7].SetActive(false);


            BGlist[rand3].SetActive(true); //Random red background
            // BGmesh.material = BGmat[rand];
            fadingBG.StopFading();
            speedManager3 += 1f;

        }


        if (speedManager3 == 912f || speedManager3 == 1815)
        {
            //Random blue background

            //Set the previous backgrounds game object to false
            BGlist[8].SetActive(false);
            BGlist[9].SetActive(false);
            BGlist[10].SetActive(false);
            BGlist[11].SetActive(false);

            BGlist[rand1].SetActive(true); //Random blue background
            // BGmesh.material = BGmat[rand];
            fadingBG.StopFading();
            speedManager3 += 1f;

        }
    }
```

So i've tried changing the material of the mesh renderer and also making individual game objects for every background that I set to active and false.

I'm using mesh renderer to make an endlessly scrolling background that follows the camera.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you call Random in the Update and that kill the performance (I know because I made the same mistake some years ago).
When you know that you want to generate multiple Random values you should do it only 1 time (for example in the Start) store them in an array and use them later. If your array is empty you can then call again the method to generate multiple random values 1 time.
Remember to never call Random in the Update, avoid to do any hard calculation every frame (that's not only include Random, also divide if possible to avoid).

Comment: Useful information, thanks! The lag issue is still there though. Moved all random.range to start and use the variable after in update.

Comment: I noticed that when it's the first background in the array the game runs smooth.

Comment: @burr try to update your code in the question. Maybe there is still something that can be changed to get better performance (or a reason why the first background works without lag)

Comment: Edited the code and it seems like the first background in each Random.Range is working with no lag.

Comment: @burr ok there are many thing that can be problematic. 1. if you need to execute a code every second there is no reason to create a variable, check if >1 and decrese by the same value... It's just a strange way to do it. Just reset the aliveTime to 0, or use InvokeRepeating (better solution). 2. why 3 random int value? Just use an array. 3. I'm not sure why speedManager3 can be multiple but accurate value (int or float). How can it be 1213? 4. Finally the problem can be in the StartFading StopFading (not sure if it's a Unity method but I did not find the docs).

Comment: Sorry that i'm late to reply and I know the code is probably very poorly written. Anyways, the way it works is that speedmanager3 increases by 10 each second. When it gets to 310 I put 'speedManager3 +=1;' to prevent it from executing all the code multiple times during that second, then I have to put the next background switch to 'speedManager = 611;' and the next 'speedManager = 912;' since i added +1 to it and then add +1 for every other switch.